# Loading xib file into an custom NSView gets embedded inside another custom NSView

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift3, interface-builder

I have a custom NSView (called `Header`) that I am able to load during runtime. However, this custom NSView (`Header`) gets embedded inside another custom NSView at run time that is bigger and it produces extra space at the bottom (I don't want this extra space). Is there another way to load a xib file that will not have this issue?

This is how it looks like: [image]

Here is how I'm loading the xib file:

```
import Cocoa

class Header: NSView {

  @IBOutlet var view: Header!
  @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: NSTextField!
  override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.draw(dirtyRect)

    // Drawing code here.
  }
  override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
    super.init(frame: frameRect)
    var topLevelObjects = NSArray()
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Header", owner: self, topLevelObjects: &topLevelObjects)

    let view = ((topLevelObjects as Array).filter { $0 is NSView })[0] as! NSView
    self.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y:0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    self.addSubview(self.view)
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't add your own header using constraints and views. Is too easy.

```
let mainContainer = UIView()
mainContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
mainContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

self.view.addSubview(mainContainer)

let views = ["mainContainer" : mainContainer]

let metrics = ["mainContainerWidth" : self.view.bounds.width]

self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[mainContainer]|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))

self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[mainContainer]|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
```

Here are a couple of examples of using VF.

I hope this help.

https://github.com/CristianCardosoA/Auto-layout-VF

Comment: For sure if you are developing NSView is for iOS desktop applications, if not use UIView. Here are a couple of examples using NSView. http://www.knowstack.com/swift-autolayout-visual-format-language-sample-code/